# Unspin text in php from spun text on sentence level

Tags: php, regex

I need to neatly output spun text in a php page.
I already have the prespun text in {hi|hello|greetings} format.
I have a php code that i found elsewhere, but it does not output the spun text on sentence level, where two {{ come. 
Here is the code that needs fixing.

```
<?php

function spinText($text){
    $test = preg_match_all("#\{(.*?)\}#", $text, $out);

    if (!$test) return $text;

    $toFind = Array();
    $toReplace = Array();

    foreach($out[0] AS $id => $match){
    $choices = explode("|", $out[1][$id]);
    $toFind[]=$match;
    $toReplace[]=trim($choices[rand(0, count($choices)-1)]);
    }

    return str_replace($toFind, $toReplace, $text);
}

echo spinText("{Hello|Hi|Greetings}!");;

?>
```

The output will be randomly chose word: Hello OR Hi OR Greetings.

However, if there is a sentence level spinning, the output is messed up.
E.g.:

```
{{hello|hi}.{how're|how are} you|{How's|How is} it going}
```

The output is

```
{hello.how're you|How is it going}
```

As you can see the text has not been spun completely.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recursive problem, so regular expressions aren't that great; but recursive patterns can help though:

```
function bla($s)
{
    // first off, find the curly brace patterns (those that are properly balanced)
    if (preg_match_all('#\{(((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))*)\}#', $s, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        // go through the string in reverse order and replace the sections
        for ($i = count($matches[0]) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
            // we recurse into this function here
            $s = substr_replace($s, bla($matches[1][$i][0]), $matches[0][$i][1], strlen($matches[0][$i][0]));
        }
    }
    // once we're done, it should be safe to split on the pipe character
    $choices = explode('|', $s);

    return $choices[array_rand($choices)];
}

echo bla("{{hello|hi}.{how're|how are} you|{How's|How is} it going}"), "\n";
```

See also: [Recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php)