# Is the order of a preg_offset_capture sub-array *guaranteed* to be increasing offset?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I haven't been able to find an authoritative answer to this, though I'm 99.9% certain it's true. Things like the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037433/unspin-text-in-php-from-spun-text-on-sentence-level/15037819#15037819) to  rely on it's being true, as I expect lots of other code does. But can someone who really knows something about `preg_match_all` (not by observation but by specified requirement or specified algorithm) confirm that this is guaranteed behavior?  I can't glean it from the documentation.

**My use case is very simple:**

```
preg_match_all("/$regexp/", $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

And I know that `$regexp` does not contain any sub-patterns, so the documentation tells me that `$matches[0]` will be an array of 2-element arrays, where each sub-array has elements with numeric key 0 containing a string that matched the pattern, and numeric key 1 containing the offset into `$content` at which the match occurred.  And while it only seems reasonable that the array elements would be ordered by increasing offset, I don't see where that is required, such that it would be a bug if it weren't the case.  Although I can't imagine just how it could be done to useful effect, perhaps there might be some way to implement `preg_match_all` with multiple threads that append their partial results without merging into fully-sorted order.

In my particular case, I only care about offsets, not the strings that were matched, but it's critical that the offsets be increasing.  So with belt-and-suspenders mentality I coded:

```
preg_match_all("/$regexp/", $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$offsets = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $offsets[] = $match[1];
}
sort($offsets);
```

So put another way, is the final `sort($offsets)` a guaranteed waste of cycles?

And if it won't get me in deep trouble for asking a related but potentially separate question, if the sort were potentially useful, would it be more/less/same efficient to take the default `SORT_REGULAR` flag as shown, or to specify `SORT_NUMERIC` explicitly, given that the offsets produced within `preg_match_all` are necessarily numeric?

Comment: Interesting question. (Had an answer, but spoke too soon - before reading entire question - _D'oh!_)

Comment: Someone will have to look at the [php source code](http://php.net/git.php) :)

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Each matched item is an array element that is also an array of only 2 elements, the matched string [0] and its offset [1]. I don't think the offsets are ordered in a single array. Although, this behavior might be changable in combination with other flags. But since, its sequentially built, its hard to imagine any out-of-order results. The stack is used heavily in regex to maintain positional context.

Comment: @sln The question stated there were no sub-patterns.  The result is an array with only one element, and that element is an array of two-element arrays giving the string and offset for each match of the entire pattern within the subject.  So the question was whether the order of two-element arrays was specified as being by increasing offset value.  It appears the order is not *specified*, but the current php implementation guarantees it will be so.

Comment: @sootsnoot - Actually, the order found by any engine is always sequential from left to right. Its follows the same order as found when parsing the expression. So within each sub-expression the offset must always be greater than or equal to its sub-expression predacesor. Therefore each match just appends its results into its respective expression element. On a side note, backtracking is the 800 lb. gorilla here. Coordinating threading in that light would not be trivial (my opinion).

Comment: @sln I agree that in general, regular expressions with quantifiers make effective use of threads impractical.  However, an implementation could examine both the expression and the subject string to determine special cases in which threads could be beneficial.  For example a regexp consisting of a single plain character, and a multi-megabyte subject string.  In that case, splitting the subject into several segments and running the scan in parallel could well be worthwhile, even considering the overhead.  Requiring the result in offset order could add to the overhead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your question on string offset order:

Full matches should always be in ascending string offset order.  PHP implements global matching with a loop that sets the `start_offset`
at the end of the most recent full match until the end of the subject string.  That is, it finds the first match, then the second, then 
the third, and so on.

If you'd like to verify that I'm not horribly misreading the source code (or missing something significant), you can look at the function
`php_pcre_match_impl` in `ext/pcre/php_pcre.c`.  `preg_match_all` sets the global parameter to 1.  What clued me into it was a comment at the end 
of the do while loop for `global`:

```
/*Advance to the position right after the last full match*/
start_offset = offsets[1];
```

If global is set, then the loop repeats with the new offset and `pcre_exec` is called again with it.

Regarding your SORT_NUMERIC question:

It's hard to say.  Setting `SORT_NUMERIC` makes sort use the `numeric_compare_function` to do element comparisons, where `SORT_REGULAR` uses `compare_function`.

`compare_function` does a type check and then decides what to do for the comparison from there, whereas `numeric_compare_function` just blindly converts both into
`double`s.  With both being LONGs `compare_function` just compares them without doing any kind of conversion.  So it would ultimately depend on which is faster: blindly converting to double, or performing the type checking.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer because it fully explains where the information came from.  It doesn't answer the question as I asked it, where I wanted to know if the ordering was *specified*. It appears that it isn't, so a clever php implementer *could* decide to optimize the existing code for the special case of a simple string pattern within a long subject by splitting the subject into segments and searching in parallel without ordering the final result.  But with the current implementation and use in the field, that probably wouldn't be accepted.  Great answer on SORT_NUMERIC!